# Does interviewer use you as a survey for job searching website after finishing interviews?

Tags: interviewing, malaysia

After I went about three interviews, I notice that 2 of the companies just somehow ask me what capability, strength, the normal typical interview question. I answered them, and  they will contact me back if they are interested with me.

Later I saw the job posted on the job searching website with the same position they offered me, but they only change the naming (for example they want to hire functional consultant through my email but in the job searching website, they change to junior consultant, the criteria is  the same thing they asked in the interview)

Is this something common to use candidates from interviews as a test market. I don't know if in my country, Malaysia, does this often or not but seems for me I am quite upset about this.

Comment: What survey? They interviewed you. Why would they stop looking for candidates if you haven't accepted an offer from them yet? I don't understand why you're upset.

Comment: Givng you an interview is not offering you a job, in fact, saying they will contact you if they are interested confirms that they have not offered you a job yet.

Comment: i wasnt upset where i didnt get the job  or not.i am not really keen if i got it from the two companies.   Is somehow what we asian call as' test water'.something like they just try to test the current job applicant market ..sorry i dont know how to define it

Comment: Was there some promise of exclusivity for you as a candidate when you interviewed? Or does the title given on the website describe a much lesser position than the one your interviewed for?  Do you feel like they enticed you to interview for the position by giving it a better-sounding title than it actually deserves when they are really filling a lower-level position? I'm trying to get a better grip on what you find upsetting.

Comment: it sounds like they want someone like you, but for less money.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They interviewed you, ask for your feedback then, took your feedback and used it adjust the Job Spec. Basically they are interviewing people to help then figure out what they need - once they know that, they will start seriously interviewing people, maybe.

I know this sound malicious, but they just trying to find their way, and simply don't know how to hire for this specific position. In there mind if you are a good fit they will hire you - even if the likelihood of that happening is small, so there is nothing wrong with it.

This is very common, though the blatantly asking for feedback before giving you there decision is clearly (at least somewhat) abusive and less common.

**There's nothing you can do about it, just move on and don't let it upset you.**

Comment: Yep, happens a lot.  Not a biggie.

Comment: `though the blatantly asking for feedback before giving you there decision is clearly (at least somewhat) abusive and less common.` This sometime can be see as a redflag for interviewer as you not being either calm or patient, just keep looking and wait for responses

Comment: i see.thank you for explaining. No i didnt ask for feedback as i said i wasnt aiming  for the positions anyway after seeing the condition of the office.i just want to know why they do such thing after interviews.Sounds like a fake interview but thanks

Comment: @Rob intteresting to see this  in north america

Comment: @Rob honestly ,this make feel like my interviews are just been made like i dont know just testing prototype kinda situation